# Using range names as cell source

Tags: openoffice-calc, named-ranges

I've been trying to work on this thing in OpenOffice Calc, where I have two drop lists in a spreadsheet, in which data is coming from other columns. I've attached a snapshot for better understanding.

[image: Example]

Cells A1-A3 are represented by named-range `countries`
Cells B2-B3 are represented by name-range `country1`.

Named-ranges `country2` and `country3` represent B5-B6 and B8-B9 respectively.

Cell A11 is a drop down list with range 'countries' as source so that it contains values : INDIA, ENGLAND ,AUSTRALIA.

Cell B11 is another drop down list whose values are to be determined by the value chosen in A11 i.e. B11 is dependant on A11. As an example, if I choose 'England', then values in B11 must contain IJ, KL. In other words, a named-range has to be set as source for B11 depending on value from A11.

Now the problem is, if I directly set the source of B11 with some named-range, say country1, it's successfully showing the values. I've shown the same here:

[image: successfully showing the values]

but when I'm retrieving the same range name using formula, it's not showing the range. Rather it just sets the name of the range as value, as shown here

[image: not showing the range]

The formula I've used for obtaining a range for source is:

```
CONCATENATE("country" & MATCH(A11;countries;0))
```

Can someone explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap the formula in an `INDIRECT` to get Calc to evaluate the range name.

As a side note, the `&` has the same function as `CONCATENATE`, there's no need to use both.  So either of these formulas will work:

```
INDIRECT("country" & MATCH(A11;countries;0))
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("country";MATCH(A11;countries;0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works :)
And thanks for info about concatenate also. I didn't know about that :)